# Term for the function $f(x,y)=x/\text{(the highest power of y dividing x)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, binary-operations

I'm wondering if there's a term and/or sign already out there for a binary operation on the integers equivalent  to $f(x, y) = x / Y$, where $Y$ is the highest power of $y$ that divides $x$, and $y ≠ 0$. I use idempotent in the title to mean that the function $g(x) = f(x, y)$ is idempotent for any nonzero integer $y$. It is equivalent to dividing until there's no division left to be done.

For example (using ⨸ as a placeholder sign):
$$
200 ⨸ 10 = 2,\\
432 ⨸ 12 = 3,\\
216 ⨸ 3 = 8,\\
300 ⨸ 7 = 300
$$

Note that, in the fourth example, $Y = 7^0 = 1$.
Or an algebraic example, the equation that got me thinking about this in the first place:
$2Z ⨸ 2 = 2Z + 1$, where $Z$ is the set of integers.

Comment: Do you know about $p$-adic valuations? You can write this operation using them, although it doesn't give a single symbol for this operation.

Comment: I took the liberty of making your title more explicit. It was pretty vague before and probably would not have attracted as much attention as a clear title.  Also please read this [brief tutorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on how to use the markup here. I did that for you too, this time,  but you should try it out for yourself.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Wow, it had never crossed my mind that p-adic numbers had anything to do with this, thank you for telling me about that.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you for the edit, and for sharing the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is prime it's common to write $v_p(n)$ (the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) or valuation) for the highest power of $p$ dividing $n$, so that in the special case that you're dividing by a prime we can write

$$f(n, p) = \frac{n}{p^{v_p(n)}}.$$

This operation is pretty poorly behaved if $p$ isn't prime and in that case I'm not aware of any common notation for it. Note that in the prime case $f(n, p)$ is multiplicative in $n$: we have $f(nm, p) = f(n, p) f(m, p)$, which isn't true in the nonprime case.

Comment: Great answer! What exactly do you mean by poorly behaved though, if you could elaborate?

Comment: I just mean the thing I said immediately after that, that it's no longer multiplicative in the first variable. Probably there are other things too. An equivalent statement is that $v_p(n)$ only satisfies $v_p(nm) = v_p(n) + v_p(m)$ if $p$ is prime.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.